# a = -2147483648 - a; compiler optimization

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to learn how to reverse engineer software and all the tricks to understand how the code looks like before the compiler optimizations.

I found something like this several times:

```
    if (a < 0)
      a = -2147483648 - a;
```

I originally thought it was an `abs()`: a underflows so you get the positive value. But since `a` is negative (see the if), this is equivalent to:

```
    if (a < 0)
      a = -2147483648 + abs(a);
```

Which will be a very small negative number, and not the absolute value of `a` at all. What am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything.  You could use abs(a) | 0x80000000 instead.  No idea why that would be useful.

Comment: From http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html --
"So, to the computer, taking the negative of a number, that is, subtracting a number from 0, is the same as inverting the bits and adding one, which is where the trick comes from".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is converting the number so that bit 31 becomes a sign bit, and the rest bits (0...30) denotes the absolute magnitude. e.g. if a = -5, then after the operation it becomes 0x80000005.

Comment: In other words it's a conversion from two's complement to sign magnitude. (I wonder where that's useful in a typical compiler.)

Comment: @Gilles: it may be the actual application code and not an optimization from the compiler. I just assumed it was an optimization because it looked like one.

Comment: Any suggestion why the reverse engineered software would be doing this often enough for the OP to notice it in particular? I was thinking about the possibility that this was part of a software conversion from int to IEEE 754 floating-point representation, but it seems to me that it would always be simpler to position the sign bit last in these cases.

Comment: For integers which can be represented in this way having a number in this format would be very useful for printing out signed integers or getting ready to do multiplication or division on machines that can't do signed versions of those operations natively.

Comment: @Pascal: I don't know. We need more context from @Andreas.

Comment: The part of the code I was looking at was a patching algorithm that uses a modified BSDIFF algorithm. I was trying to figure out the kind of modifications they did to that algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be converting from [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement) to [sign-magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement ?

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely hope that the original source said 0x80000000 and not -2147483648 ! The hex number at least gives the reader a clue. The decimal is very cryptic.

Comment: Being it decompiled code, I have no way to know what the original source says. Also, this should be a comment.

Comment: That's why I said "I hope the original source ..." I presumed if you're decompiling that you don't have the original source.